# AngularJS: Using an attribute set in one directive, within another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

### Scenario

Lets say I have two directives `first` and `second` where the directives are used on the *same* DOM element as such:

***HTML***

```
<div first second></div>
```

---

***Javascript***

```
//first directive
.directive('first', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.attr('someAttr', 1234);
        element.html('I have the attribute value: ' + element.attr('someAttr'));
       }
   };
})
// second directive
.directive('second', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 0,
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        // the elements attribute `someAttr` is undefined here
    }
   };   
})
```

The `first` directive adds an attribute (`someAttr`) to the element where it is being used.

### Problem

What I want to achieve is that *access/use* the set value to `someAttr` (set in `first directive`) in the `second` directive's link/controller function. But for the moment, I haven't been successful in doing so. ([***Check this fiddle out***](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/neqesaLa/))

**Note:** I've also set the priority of the `first` directive to a value higher than that of `second`, but still when you log the attributes of the element where the directive is used, there is no `someAttr` attribute in the set.

***Also note that if how I want to achieve the communication between directives is not appropriate, then what is the right way to do so? Any help would be appreciated***.

Comment: what is the practical problem you are trying to solve here? there are much better ways to enable directives to communicate with each other....

Comment: The real reason I want to access the attribute between those directives is that, in fact, the first directive (_in my own case `uid` directive_) generates a unique id for the DOM element. Whereas the the second directive (_`storeJSON`_ directive) is responsible for creating/storing a DOM JS object based on the unique ID set in the first directive, as well as placing this object in the appropriate position, in a hierarchy of DOM JS objects.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cannot detect changes in attributes set to the DOM element directly (at least not in angularjs way).

Try using a property in the first directive controller and then 'require' 'first' in 'second' to access 'second' properties.

Check the information about the 'requires' property when defining a directive to see how it works.

UPDATE: Check this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bEbO8LvCIUd0NZPFqMnv?p=preview

```
app.directive('first', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.html('I (first) have the scope value: ' + scope.data.attribute);
       },
       controller: function($scope) {
         this.data = $scope.data = {
           attribute: 1234
         };
       }
   };
});
// second directive
app.directive('second', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'first',
    priority: 1,
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, firstController){
        element.html(element.html() + ' and I (second) have access to that value too: ' + firstController.data.attribute);
        //you can $scope.$watch firstController.data changes here too
    }
   };   
});
```